# Static variables used as constants return zero in other class

Tags: c++, static, constructor

I have a class that I'm using to store some static default variables for a visual experiment I'm creating.

They are not marked as const, because Im using a GUI to tweak them at runtime.
When I log them in the main class ( which calls the static function init on the Defaults class ) - they are valid. But in the constructor of the different class it returns zero.

The output looks like this

```
"Constants::init() called" // Constants::Heads::MIN_LIFETIME initialized to 1200
preSetup-Log  Constants::Heads::MIN_LIFETIME 1200
PhysicsObject- Constants::Heads::MIN_LIFETIME 0 // Y you zero?
postSetup-Log  Constants::Heads::MIN_LIFETIME 1200
```

I'm defining the constants like this:

```
namespace Constants {
    namespace Forces {
        static int MAX_LIFETIME;
        static float GRAVITY_FORCE;
    };
}


static void init() {
    std::cout << "Constants::init()" << std::endl;
    Constants::Forces::GRAVITY_FORCE = 40000.0f;
    Constants::Forces::MAX_LIFETIME = 3000;
}
```

Comment: Can you post minimal code that reproduces the error?

Comment: Could you show some code from your program?

Comment: Please post the relevant sections of the .h and .cc files.

Comment: @Onedayitwillmake: Are you aware that objects marked `static` have internal linkage so you will get a distinct set of objects in each translation unit in your program? If you tweak them in one translation unit it won't affect the values of the copies in the other translation units.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// header.h
namespace Constants {
    namespace Forces {
    extern int MAX_LIFETIME;
    extern float GRAVITY_FORCE;
    }
}

// my_constants.cpp
namespace Constants {
    namespace Forces {
        int MAX_LIFETIME = 3000;
        float GRAVITY_FORCE = 40000.0f;
     }
}
```

Then include `header.h` in a file that uses the constants. The constants will be initialized automatically when the program starts.

Answer (score 4):

This is because when you declare a variable `static` inside a (say `.h`) file and include that file in various `.cpp` files then for **every .cpp file (translation unit), a separate copy of the variable is created**. For example,

```
// x.h ...
    namespace Forces {
        static int MAX_LIFETIME;  // unique copy for each translation unit (.cpp)
        static float GRAVITY_FORCE;  // same as above

        extern int SOMETHING; //<----- creates only single copy 
    };
```

As shown, you should create the variable as **`extern`** inside the `namespace` and define that variable in only one of the `.cpp` files.

**Other way** is to enclose them inside a `class` instead of `namespace`:

```
class Forces {
    static int MAX_LIFETIME;  // only 1 copy
    static float GRAVITY_FORCE;  // only 1 copy
};
```

You still have to define them in one of the `.cpp` files as,

```
int Forces::MAX_LIFETIME = <>;
```

Comment: So for what I am trying to achieve, what might be a good way to achieve it. I would prefer not to have externs if possible.

Comment: @user4683: What is your objection to externs?